# How can I input this simple text file, process it, and export to another text file?

Tags: import, text, html

I will try to keep this example very specific and simple. Let us say I have a text file called `file.txt`, with path `C:/Ruffle/bunch-of-files/file.txt`, and with content as follows:

```
Hello, XXX, you YYY!
```

And I have also got two files containing ordered lists, namely `names.txt` and `epithets.txt`, both in directory `C:/Ruffle/bunch-of-lists/` and with content as follows:

```
{John, Mary, Algernon}

{Honey Biscuit, Old Twit, Wonderful Person}
```

What do I need to put in a short Mathematica notebook that

- imports `file.txt`
- applies specified rules to choose an element from `names.txt` and another from `epithets.txt` (for example, let's say in one case it chooses an element randomly and in the other it chooses the nth where `n = 1 + Mod[DateList[][[3]], 3]`)
- substitutes them for "XXX" and "YYY" respectively
- saves the result as `C:/Ruffle/bunch-of-amended-files/amended-file.txt`
- closes `file.txt`

?

(The reason I have assigned this question an `HTML` tag as well as a `text` one is that what I need is to output HTML files. So `amended-file.txt` would actually be `amended-file.html`, and the Mathematica notebook would also have to insert a specified header and tags. But since an HTML file is only a text file, the problem is one of text processing, and I am trying to keep the question as simple as possible.)

Comment: It might ease things a bit if your text files use the conventional template format for *Mathematica* strings: ``tmp = StringTemplate["Hello, `name`, you `epiphet`!"];``. With that, `tmp @ <|"name" -> "John", "epiphet" -> "old twit"|>` will generate the desired sentence.

Comment: 1) see FileTemplateApply and friends, or StringReplace 2) consider storing values in separate file rather than notebooks which only make extracting them problematic 3) where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question so that names and epithets are stored in text files rather than notebooks, but I will have to think on this further before specifying better where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

```
OutputForm@"Hello, XXX, you YYY" >> file.txt
{"John", "Mary", "Algernon"} >> names.txt
{"Honey Biscuit", "Old Twit", "Wonderful Person"} >> epithets.txt
```

```
StringReplace[
    Import["file.txt", "Text"]
  , { "XXX" -> RandomChoice@Get@"names.txt"
    , "YYY" -> Get["epithets.txt"][[1 + Mod[DateList[][[3]], 3]]]
    }
 ] // OutputForm >> amended-file.txt
```

```
FilePrint@"file.txt"
FilePrint@"amended-file.txt"
```

> Hello, XXX, you YYY
>
> Hello, Algernon, you Wonderful Person

p.s. `OutputForm` is used to drop quote marks when string is `Put`. Alternative would be `Export[#, "Text"]&`.